# Rider IDE not using css/javascript from wwwroot

Tags: asp.net-core, rider

I've recently (attempted to) switch to the Rider IDE by Jetbrains for .NET Core development. It's just something I'd like to try and see if I prefer it over visual studio.

I've successfully imported the project into Rider and I can run the site and it loads the website, however it does not seem to be serving the content in the `wwwroot` directory (so javascript and css). Which results in my pages looking very empty.

Is there some option I need to set to include this wwwroot? I've not changed anything other than just importing the Visual Studio solution in Rider.

[image]

My .csproj includes the `wwwroot` directory correctly:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="assets\images\" />
    <Folder Include="assets\other\" />
    <Folder Include="Imports\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\FineUploader\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This same solution works perfectly in Visual Studio 17.

Comment: Note the console says: Environment Production. Is it possible the behavior is different in Dev vs Prod? On VS 2017 you have IIS Express also involved and not with Rider. Try editing the debugging profile and set the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development. At least you should see some logs on console if you have that enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the same issue by going to Startup.cs and adding `app.UseStaticFiles();` above `app.UseMvc()` in the `Configure` function.